# How to add select tag text to input?

Tags: javascript, html

This code only add select tag value to input.

```
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("myid").value = e.target.value
}
```

I want to add text.

This code has not working:

```
function myFunction(e) {
        document.getElementById("myid").value = e.target.text
    }
```

Html code:

```
<select onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="0">Text 1</option>
    <option value="1">Text 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myid">
```

Comment: you can use `document.getElementById("myid").value= e.target.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text` to get option text value

```js
function myFunction(e) {
        document.getElementById("myid").value = e.target.value === "" ? "" : e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].text
    }
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction(event)">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="0">Text 1</option>
    <option value="1">Text 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myid">
```

Comment: I want to add text.

Comment: `Please select ...` Do not add

Comment: @MahdiHosseinpour i have added condition

Answer (score 1):

You want this.

I am passing the select itself and using the longhand to get at the textual content

I also test to make sure the field will not contain "Please select..."

```js
function myFunction(sel) {
  document.getElementById("myid").value = sel.selectedIndex < 1 ? "" : sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text; // or .textContent
}
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction(this)">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="0">Text 1</option>
  <option value="1">Text 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myid">
```

Here is an unobtrusive version

```js
document.getElementById("sel").addEventListener("change", function() {
  document.getElementById("myid").value = this.selectedIndex < 1 ? "" : this.options[this.selectedIndex].text; // or .textContent
})
```

```html
<select id="sel">
  <option value="">Please select...</option>
  <option value="0">Text 1</option>
  <option value="1">Text 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myid">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `textContent` and instead of passing the event pass the element using the `this` keyword

```js
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("myid").value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].textContent
    }
```

```html
<select onchange="myFunction(this)">
    <option value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="0">Text 1</option>
    <option value="1">Text 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="myid">
```

Comment: .text is also valid and I already answered using (this)  - using (e) is misleading in my opinion

Comment: `Please select ...` Do not add